# RED.xml - Library specification file was not generated for 'Library.class.name' library

Tags: robotframework

Red.xml - I get this error when uploading the java jar files using the button Add Java Library.

> Library specification file was not generated for 'Library.class.name'
>   library

Tried the below steps,

1. Removed Build Automatically from Eclipse and did Project - > Clean
2. Re-Exported the jar file of java class files.

Note: When built from Shell script, I was able to build and execute the same code successfully. 
Somewhere when building the class files this issue occurs. But unsure how to rectify it.

When reloaded the referenced library class file, received the below error,

Library specification generation problem

```
Problem occurred during generating libdoc for 'com.KTOC.TRB.testautomation.ObjectRepository.pg_SF_Login' library located at '/Users/roja/Automation/Jars-For-KTOC/TRBJars1.jar'.
RED python session problem. Following exception has been thrown by python service:
        Traceback (most recent call last):
          File "/var/folders/dv/nnfc_k29377bv7s34kng7qgh0000gn/T/RobotTempDir8808901746972554502/robot_session_server.py", line 38, in inner
            result['result'] = func(*args, **kwargs)
          File "/var/folders/dv/nnfc_k29377bv7s34kng7qgh0000gn/T/RobotTempDir8808901746972554502/robot_session_server.py", line 84, in inner
            return to_call(*args, **kwargs)
          File "/var/folders/dv/nnfc_k29377bv7s34kng7qgh0000gn/T/RobotTempDir8808901746972554502/robot_session_server.py", line 116, in inner
            return to_call(*args, **kwargs)
          File "/var/folders/dv/nnfc_k29377bv7s34kng7qgh0000gn/T/RobotTempDir8808901746972554502/robot_session_server.py", line 59, in inner
            return func(*args, **kwargs)
          File "/var/folders/dv/nnfc_k29377bv7s34kng7qgh0000gn/T/RobotTempDir8808901746972554502/robot_session_server.py", line 305, in create_libdoc
            return red_libraries.create_libdoc(libname, format)
          File "/private/var/folders/dv/nnfc_k29377bv7s34kng7qgh0000gn/T/RobotTempDir8808901746972554502/red_libraries.py", line 64, in create_libdoc
            raise Exception(result)
        Exception: Importing test library 'com.KTOC.TRB.testautomation.ObjectRepository.pg_SF_Login' failed: NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class com.KTOC.TRB.testautomation.ObjectRepository.pg_SF_Login
        java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: 
            at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
            at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:348)
            at robot.utils.importer$py._import$14(/usr/local/Cellar/jython/2.7.1/libexec/Lib/site-packages/robot/utils/importer.py:167)
            at robot.utils.importer$py.call_function(/usr/local/Cellar/jython/2.7.1/libexec/Lib/site-packages/robot/utils/importer.py)
            at robot.utils.importer$py.import_$32(/usr/local/Cellar/jython/2.7.1/libexec/Lib/site-packages/robot/utils/importer.py:274)
            at robot.utils.importer$py.call_function(/usr/local/Cellar/jython/2.7.1/libexec/Lib/site-packages/robot/utils/importer.py)
            at robot.utils.importer$py._import_class_or_module$5(/usr/local/Cellar/jython/2.7.1/libexec/Lib/site-packages/robot/utils/importer.py:77)
            at robot.utils.importer$py.call_function(/usr/local/Cellar/jython/2.7.1/libexec/Lib/site-packages/robot/utils/importer.py)
            at robot.utils.importer$py.import_class_or_module$4(/usr/local/Cellar/jython/2.7.1/libexec/Lib/site-packages/robot/utils/importer.py:74)
            at robot.utils.importer$py.call_function(/usr/local/Cellar/jython/2.7.1/libexec/Lib/site-packages/robot/utils/importer.py)
            at robot.libdocpkg.robotbuilder$py.build$2(/usr/local/Cellar/jython/2.7.1/libexec/Lib/site-packages/robot/libdocpkg/robotbuilder.py:40)
            at robot.libdocpkg.robotbuilder$py.call_function(/usr/local/Cellar/jython/2.7.1/libexec/Lib/site-packages/robot/libdocpkg/robotbuilder.py)
            at robot.libdocpkg$py.LibraryDocumentation$1(/usr/local/Cellar/jython/2.7.1/libexec/Lib/site-packages/robot/libdocpkg/__init__.py:47)
            at robot.libdocpkg$py.call_function(/usr/local/Cellar/jython/2.7.1/libexec/Lib/site-packages/robot/libdocpkg/__init__.py)
            at robot.libdoc$py.main$4(/usr/local/Cellar/jython/2.7.1/libexec/Lib/site-packages/robot/libdoc.py:163)
            at robot.libdoc$py.call_function(/usr/local/Cellar/jython/2.7.1/libexec/Lib/site-packages/robot/libdoc.py)
            at robot.utils.application$py._execute$10(/usr/local/Cellar/jython/2.7.1/libexec/Lib/site-packages/robot/utils/application.py:94)
            at robot.utils.application$py.call_function(/usr/local/Cellar/jython/2.7.1/libexec/Lib/site-packages/robot/utils/application.py)
            at robot.utils.application$py.execute$9(/usr/local/Cellar/jython/2.7.1/libexec/Lib/site-packages/robot/utils/application.py:79)
            at robot.utils.application$py.call_function(/usr/local/Cellar/jython/2.7.1/libexec/Lib/site-packages/robot/utils/application.py)
            at robot.libdoc$py.libdoc$9(/usr/local/Cellar/jython/2.7.1/libexec/Lib/site-packages/robot/libdoc.py:223)
            at robot.libdoc$py.call_function(/usr/local/Cellar/jython/2.7.1/libexec/Lib/site-packages/robot/libdoc.py)
            at red_libraries$py._create_libdoc_with_stdout_redirect$5(/private/var/folders/dv/nnfc_k29377bv7s34kng7qgh0000gn/T/RobotTempDir8808901746972554502/red_libraries.py:83)
            at red_libraries$py.call_function(/private/var/folders/dv/nnfc_k29377bv7s34kng7qgh0000gn/T/RobotTempDir8808901746972554502/red_libraries.py)
            at red_libraries$py.create_libdoc$4(/private/var/folders/dv/nnfc_k29377bv7s34kng7qgh0000gn/T/RobotTempDir8808901746972554502/red_libraries.py:66)
            at red_libraries$py.call_function(/private/var/folders/dv/nnfc_k29377bv7s34kng7qgh0000gn/T/RobotTempDir8808901746972554502/red_libraries.py)
            at SimpleXMLRPCServer$py._dispatch$15(/usr/local/Cellar/jython/2.7.1/libexec/Lib/SimpleXMLRPCServer.py:422)
            at SimpleXMLRPCServer$py.call_function(/usr/local/Cellar/jython/2.7.1/libexec/Lib/SimpleXMLRPCServer.py)
            at SimpleXMLRPCServer$py._marshaled_dispatch$10(/usr/local/Cellar/jython/2.7.1/libexec/Lib/SimpleXMLRPCServer.py:276)
            at SimpleXMLRPCServer$py.call_function(/usr/local/Cellar/jython/2.7.1/libexec/Lib/SimpleXMLRPCServer.py)
            at SimpleXMLRPCServer$py.do_POST$19(/usr/local/Cellar/jython/2.7.1/libexec/Lib/SimpleXMLRPCServer.py:535)
            at SimpleXMLRPCServer$py.call_function(/usr/local/Cellar/jython/2.7.1/libexec/Lib/SimpleXMLRPCServer.py)
            at BaseHTTPServer$py.handle_one_request$7(/usr/local/Cellar/jython/2.7.1/libexec/Lib/BaseHTTPServer.py:345)
            at BaseHTTPServer$py.call_function(/usr/local/Cellar/jython/2.7.1/libexec/Lib/BaseHTTPServer.py)
            at BaseHTTPServer$py.handle$8(/usr/local/Cellar/jython/2.7.1/libexec/Lib/BaseHTTPServer.py:352)
            at BaseHTTPServer$py.call_function(/usr/local/Cellar/jython/2.7.1/libexec/Lib/BaseHTTPServer.py)
            at SocketServer$py.__init__$47(/usr/local/Cellar/jython/2.7.1/libexec/Lib/SocketServer.py:659)
            at SocketServer$py.call_function(/usr/local/Cellar/jython/2.7.1/libexec/Lib/SocketServer.py)
            at SocketServer$py.finish_request$13(/usr/local/Cellar/jython/2.7.1/libexec/Lib/SocketServer.py:334)
            at SocketServer$py.call_function(/usr/local/Cellar/jython/2.7.1/libexec/Lib/SocketServer.py)
            at SocketServer$py.process_request$11(/usr/local/Cellar/jython/2.7.1/libexec/Lib/SocketServer.py:322)
            at SocketServer$py.call_function(/usr/local/Cellar/jython/2.7.1/libexec/Lib/SocketServer.py)
            at SocketServer$py._handle_request_noblock$8(/usr/local/Cellar/jython/2.7.1/libexec/Lib/SocketServer.py:298)
            at SocketServer$py.call_function(/usr/local/Cellar/jython/2.7.1/libexec/Lib/SocketServer.py)
            at SocketServer$py.serve_forever$5(/usr/local/Cellar/jython/2.7.1/libexec/Lib/SocketServer.py:241)
            at SocketServer$py.call_function(/usr/local/Cellar/jython/2.7.1/libexec/Lib/SocketServer.py)
        PYTHONPATH:
          /Users/roja/Automation/Jars-For-KTOC/TRBJars1.jar
          /private/var/folders/dv/nnfc_k29377bv7s34kng7qgh0000gn/T/RobotTempDir8808901746972554502
          /usr/local/Cellar/jython/2.7.1/libexec/Lib
          __classpath__
          __pyclasspath__/
          /usr/local/Cellar/jython/2.7.1/libexec/Lib/site-packages
        CLASSPATH:
          ../../../../usr/local/Cellar/jython/2.7.1/libexec/jython.jar
          .

        Try --help for usage information.
```

Below Code in Xls_Reader.java file

```
/**
 * 
 */

package com.KTOC.TRB.testautomation.Utilities;

import org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFCell;
import org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFRow;
import org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFSheet;
import org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFWorkbook;

import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.util.Hashtable;

public class Xls_Reader {
 public String path;
 public FileInputStream fis = null;
 private static XSSFWorkbook workbook = null;
 private static XSSFSheet sheet = null;
 public XSSFRow row = null;
 private XSSFCell cell = null;
 public static Xls_Reader xlsx;
 public static final String ROBOT_LIBRARY_SCOPE = "GLOBAL";

 Xls_Reader (String path) {

ClassLoader classloader = getClass().getClassLoader();
try {
  InputStream fis = classloader.getResourceAsStream(path);
  workbook = new XSSFWorkbook(fis);
  sheet = workbook.getSheetAt(0);
  fis.close();
} catch (Exception e) {
}
}

String getCellData(String sheetnam, int colnum, int rownum) {

try {
  if (rownum <= 0) {
    return "";
  }
  int index = workbook.getSheetIndex(sheetnam);
  if (index == -1) {
    return "";
  }
  sheet = workbook.getSheetAt(index);
  row = sheet.getRow(rownum - 1);
  if (row == null) {
    return "";
  }
  cell = row.getCell(colnum);
  if (cell == null) {
    return "";
  }

} catch (Exception ignored) {

}

 return cell.toString();
 }

// returns the row count in a sheet
public int getRowCount(String sheetName) {
int index = workbook.getSheetIndex(sheetName);
if (index == -1) {
  return 0;
} else {
  sheet = workbook.getSheetAt(index);
  return sheet.getLastRowNum() + 1;
}
}

// returns number of columns in a sheet
public int getColumnCount(String sheetName) {
sheet = workbook.getSheet(sheetName);
row = sheet.getRow(0);

if (row == null) {
  return -1;
}
return row.getLastCellNum();
}

 public static String getData(String SheetName, String TestCase, String parameter) 
 {
 String parametervalue = null;
 Xls_Reader xlsx = new Xls_Reader("../Users/roja/eclipse-workspace/KTOC_TestMethods/src/testautomation/TestData/KTOCData.xlsx");
 Hashtable<String, String> hTable = getDatafromXlsx(TestCase, xlsx, SheetName);
 parametervalue = (String) hTable.get(parameter);
 return parametervalue;
}

public static Hashtable<String, String> getDatafromXlsx(String testcaseName, Xls_Reader xls, String sheetname) 
{
int testcaseStartrow = 1;
while (!xls.getCellData(sheetname, 0, testcaseStartrow).equals(testcaseName)) 
{
  testcaseStartrow++;
}
int testDataStartrownum = testcaseStartrow + 2;
int rows = 0;
while (!xls.getCellData(sheetname, 0, testDataStartrownum + rows).equals("")) 
{
  rows++;
}

int colStartRownum = testcaseStartrow + 1;
int cols = 0;
while (!xls.getCellData(sheetname, cols, colStartRownum).equals("")) 
{
  cols++;
}

Hashtable<String, String> table = null;
for (int rNum = testDataStartrownum; rNum < testDataStartrownum + rows; rNum++) {
  table = new Hashtable<String, String>();
  for (int cNum = 0; cNum < cols; cNum++) {
    String key = xls.getCellData(sheetname, cNum, colStartRownum);
    String value = xls.getCellData(sheetname, cNum, rNum);
    table.put(key, value);
  }
 }
 return table;
}
}
```

Comment: For context, the Library Specification File is only used by RED for autocomplete and documentation functionality in RED. This will not impact the functionality when running Robot Framework scripts. Is there a technical error aside from this functional one? If you have a bare bones java class that triggers this as a [mcve] for this problem it would help.

Comment: Thanks for the response @A.Kootstra .

Comment: I was able to export to jar perfectly without any error. Doesn't seem to be a technical issue from the functions. But when building it, there seems to be a technical issue. I also followed this, In Project Explorer under Robot Referenced libraries, right click on the class names and clicked Reload menu. When reloaded, received an error. I updated the question with this error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The example Robot Framework java library is taken from the Robot Framework [user guide](http://robotframework.org/robotframework/latest/RobotFrameworkUserGuide.html#test-library-scope). When exported as a regular jar file and imported in the RED project file the keywords LibSpec file is generated and in the project explorer overview the keywords are shown.

The problem occurs when RED initialises the class to read the methods and documentation and generate the LibSpec from it. This requires the class to be initialised standalone without a working Robot Framework context. If your class initialises with the expectation of certain context to be active this will throw an error when generating the LibSpec but work just fine when running your tests.

```java
/**
 * 
 */
package com.mycompany;

/**
 * @author anne
 *
 */
public class ExampleLibrary {

    public static final String ROBOT_LIBRARY_SCOPE = "GLOBAL";

    private int counter = 0;

    public void count() {
        counter += 1;
        System.out.println(counter);
    }

    public void clearCounter() {
        counter = 0;
    }
}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks @A.Kootstra ! I tried executing it with these errors. My execution is fine as usual and successful. Red error icon just scared me. :)  Note: Whenever i import project from github, im facing such errors. Could this be the reason?

Comment: Not sure what you mean with "import project from github".

Comment: I have cloned a repository from github which contains set of java project class files and Robot project test suites.After which i see the class files by default under Referenced Libraries in Red.xml. Since the path varies in my local system, i deleted all class files and added my own jar that is created from the java project.

Comment: Although I'm pretty sure that it is the class initialiser that generates the error in RED (Feel free to share it) if you want me to take a look add the link by [edit] the question)

Comment: I rebuilt a new jar files, and uploaded to Red.xml. It works except the Xls_Reader files. updating the question shortly with the jar file used.

Answer (score 0):

In my case RED.xml had a broken referece to a local library:

[image]

Once I deleted that reference (clicked on the referenced library inside RED.xml, and then clicked "Delete" key) - that annoying message "Problem occurred during generating libdoc" was gone.